# Java: Fragments are displayed on top of each other (Android)

Tags: java, android-fragments

I want to design the GUI in my app by exchanging my fragments. But when I replace the fragment using the fragment manager, only the new fragment is placed under the old one.

Here are my codes:
Java from first fragment

```
package com.example.digiramm.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.example.digiramm.R;
import com.example.digiramm.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);


        binding.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment secondfragment = new SecondFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.framelayoutDiagramm, secondfragment,null);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("name");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        binding = null;
        super.onDestroyView();

    }
}
```

XML from first fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/framelayoutDiagramm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hintergrundBild"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hintergrund" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="540dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="75dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:text="@string/geführterLernweg"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="75dp"
</FrameLayout>
```

Java from second fragment

```
package com.example.digiramm.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.digiramm.R;
import com.example.digiramm.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;


public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    public SecondFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

XML from second fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/framelayoutDiagramm2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hintergrundBild"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/hintergrund" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="540dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:text="@string/start2"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="75dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:minWidth="300dp"
        android:minHeight="300dp"
        android:text="@string/geführterLernweg2"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="75dp"/>



</FrameLayout>
```

Can someone show me the reason why the fragments are placed on top of each other and not replaced?